# Function to create GRPC server with generic protobuf service and generic tower layer parameters

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tonic, rust-tower

I'm writing a function `fn run_grpc_server<S, L>(service: S, layer: L) -> Result<(), String>` where I need to provide generic parameter for protobuf service `S` and tower layer `L`, so I can build the GRPC server combining them.

To illustrate, I modify the example
https://github.com/hyperium/tonic/blob/master/examples/src/tower/server.rs as follows:

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let greeter = MyGreeter::default();

    // The stack of middleware that our service will be wrapped in
    let layer = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
        // Apply middleware from tower
        .timeout(Duration::from_secs(30))
        // Apply our own middleware
        .layer(MyMiddlewareLayer::default())
        // Interceptors can be also be applied as middleware
        .layer(tonic::service::interceptor(intercept))
        .into_inner();

    run_grpc_server(greeter, layer).await;

    Ok(())
}

pub async fn run_grpc_server<S, L>(service: S, layer: L) -> Result<(), String>
where
    S: hello_world::greeter_server::Greeter,
    L: Clone, // not sure what other constraints to put here? Something with tower::Layer<?>
{
    let addr = "[::1]:50051".parse().unwrap();

    Server::builder()
        .layer(layer)
        .add_service(GreeterServer::new(service))
        .serve(addr)
        .await
        .map_err(|e| e.to_string())
}
```

This fails to compile even though the original `layer` in `main` is not changed and is now provided as generic parameter `L`.

The compilation error is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `L: Layer<Routes>` is not satisfied
  --> src/server.rs:63:10
   |
63 |         .serve(addr)
   |          ^^^^^ the trait `Layer<Routes>` is not implemented for `L`
   |
   = note: required for `Stack<L, Identity>` to implement `Layer<Routes>`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
56 |     L: Clone + tower::Layer<tonic::transport::server::Routes>,
   |              ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What changes are needed for `run_grpc_server` to accept `layer` as parameter of generic type `L` ?

Adding compiler suggestion `L: Clone + tower::Layer<tonic::transport::server::Routes>` doesnt fix the issue but surfaces many more errors

Comment: Have you tried doing what the compiler suggests? Namely adding the constraint `L: Clone + tower::Layer<tonic::transport::server::Routes>`

Comment: yes, however that doesnt fix the issue. On adding compiler suggestion it then throws overwhelming amount of errors.